# Arranging distinct color balls inside an equilateral triangle box.

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, permutations, contest-math, combinations

> Ten balls of the same shape and size but having different colors are
> to be arranged into an equilateral triangular box as shown. Find the
> number of ways in which this arrangement can be done

[image]

My solution approach :-
Number of ways in which we can select the center ball = $10$

Number of ways in which we can select the balls around the center ball = $^9C_6=84$
Number of ways in which we can arrange the $6$ balls around the center ball = $(6-1)!=5!=120$ as they will be in circular arrangement and we know that the circular arrangement of $n$ distinct items = $(n-1)!$
Total number of ways of arranging $6$ balls around the center ball = $84 \times 120=10080$

Number of ways of arranging the remaining $3$ balls around the corners = $(3-1)!=2!=2$

Hence the number of ways should be = $10 \times 10080 \times 2= 201600$

But this is the wrong answer. What am I doing wrong? Please help me on this !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Once you've chose the $7$ central balls, there are $3!$ choices for the corners.  All the rotations have been dealt with already.

Comment: What symmetries do you consider equivalent?  There is a threefold rotation and a twofold reflection available.  You need to specify this before the question can be answered.  You are allowing rotation of the ring of six and the three corners separately.  That cannot be correct.

Comment: @saulspatz : so shouldn't we consider the circular rotations for the the corner balls once we have considered the rotations for the central balls? But even if we multiply by 3!, then also that's not the correct answer.

Comment: The correct answer given is $1209600$.

Comment: @Ganit ohh yeah , answer is coming

Comment: What wrong I have done?

Comment: The number of ways to arrange 10 diffrent balls is 10!. Or do you consider some arangement as identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**

Choose 4 for the bottom row, and arrange them, in $10C4\times4!$ ways.

Choose 3 for the next row, and arrange them, in $6C3\times3!$ ways.

Choose 2 for the next row, and arrange them, in $3C2\times2!$ ways.

Place the final ball at the top in $1$ way.

Multiply these together to get $3628800$. But now divide by $3$ because we can rotate the whole image thus duplicating arrangements already found by a factor of $3$.

Final answer: $1209600$

**Method 2**

Choose the top ball in $10$ ways.

Choose and arrange the next row down in $9C2\times2!$ ways.

Choose and arrange the third row in $7C3\times3!$ ways.

The last four balls can be arranged at the bottom in $4!$ ways.

Multiply all these together and divide by $3$ as before and get the same answer: $1209600$.

**Method 3**

Choose the central ball in $10$ ways.

Choose the surrounding $6$ balls and arrange them in $9C6\times6!$ ways. This is not the same as a circular table arrangement: the rotations are dealt with at the end.

The last $3$ balls can be arranged in $3!$ ways.

Multiply all these together and divide by 3 for the same reason as before, and get the same answer as before: $1209600$.

Comment: I was about to post the same :) +1

Comment: Can you please explain the need to divide by $3$? is it because from the 3 sides the arrangement will look different? Also what if this was any other regular polygon box like square,pentagon,etc.?

Comment: @Ganit to understand why it is divided by to , just draw a triangular which has exactly $3$ distinct balls. Write all arrangements when you rotate it $120$ degree three times. You will see that there are just $2$ distinct arrangements. It may help you to comprehend the logic

Comment: @Ganit when you rotate a given configuration you get another configuration which has already been accounted for.